# JavaFX - runLater Runnable not called

Tags: java, javafx, runnable

I'm using JavaFX for a project. 
During startup I have a prompt that asks for data and my network class establishes a connection to a server with these data.
My network class is working asynchronously and I get the response in a callback. Depending on the response I want to open a new window (stage) from my callback.

Executing my `mainStage.setScene()` triggers an exception as expected - not called from a JavaFX Application Thread, I have to use `Platform.runLater()` but:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("run");
    }
});
```

It never prints `"run"`. Why? The `accountDataPrompt.login()` function is at the end of my JavaFX start-function and, as I said, the network connection runs asynchronously. 
The prompt is a custom JavaFX dialog ([JavaFX UI Sandbox](https://github.com/marcojakob/javafx-ui-sandbox)).

Answer (score 10):

After all your scenes are completed, JavaFX application thread will be stopped. So your next Platform.runLater() will not work.

```
Platform.setImplicitExit( false );
```

Use above code. that will solve the issue.

Comment: Not having included this single line made my whole GUI freeze. This solved the issue! Thanks!

Comment: Very usefull to write JUNIT test that need RunLater and that do not have any GUI. For example, to test a JAVAFX Service.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was such a great help. Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it by using object.wait() after the call and object.notify() in the callback before executing runLater. I guess it has something to do with the JavaFX Application Thread and that it somehow ends as soon as the start function finished without displaying any active scene or something like that.
There's a better solution for sure but at least it's a workaround..